# How to join a data frame to itself within a dplyr chain?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Occasionally, I need to join a data frame to (usually a modified) version of itself within a dplyr chain. Something like this:

```
df  <- data.frame(
     id = c(1,2,3)
   , status = c('foo','bar','meh')
   , spouseid = c(4,3,2)
)


df %>% 
  filter( status == 'foo' | status == 'bar') %>% 
  # join the filtered table to itself using the dot as the right-hand side
  left_join(., by = c('id' = 'spouseid'))
```

When I try that, I get `Error in is.data.frame(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to join the original data frame to the modified one? If so, your join line can be `left_join(df, by = c('id' = 'spouseid'))`, which will put the original data frame on the rhs. Depending on which rows you want in the final result, you could also change this to a `right_join` or `full_join`.

Comment: I'm most interested in joining the edited data frame to itself without having to break the chain. In the past, I've always done my edits first, stored that in a new object, then done the joining or made the same edits within the join itself on the y argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that using the dot just moves around the left hand side, so the way it's written above only passes the lhs into `left_join()`. To use the dot for both the left- and right-hand sides, use the dot twice:

```
df %>% 
  filter( status == 'foo' | status == 'bar') %>% 
  # the first dot is x argument and the second dot is the y argument
  left_join(
      x = . 
    , y = . 
    , by = c('id' = 'spouseid')
  )
```

This way, you're passing the lhs to both arguments of `left_join()` rather than relying on magrittr's implicit lhs like you normally would.

Comment: You can also drop the `x = ` and `y = ` and use `left_join(., ., by = c('id' = 'spouseid'))`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work:
df <- data.frame(Team = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D"),
                 Date = c("2016-05-10","2016-05-10", "2016-05-10", "2016-05-10",
                          "2016-05-12", "2016-05-12", "2016-05-12",
                          "2016-05-15","2016-05-15",
                          "2016-05-30", "2016-05-30"), 
                 Points = c(1,4,3,2,1,5,6,1,2,3,9)
)

df %>% left_join(., . %>% 
                   distinct(Team, Date) %>% 
                   mutate(Date_Lagged = lag(Date)))