# Executing two self-joins after another to filter on two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, self-join

Let's assume the following dataframe:

```r
library(dplyr)

dat <- tibble(
    Structure = c("A", "B", "X", "A-X", "B-X", "C-X", "A-Y"), 
    FirstComponent = c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "C", "A"), 
    SecondComponent = c(NA, NA, NA, "X", "X", "X", "Y"),
    IsValid = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

dat
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  Structure FirstComponent SecondComponent IsValid
  <chr>     <chr>          <chr>           <lgl>  
1 A         NA             NA              FALSE  
2 B         NA             NA              FALSE  
3 X         NA             NA              FALSE  
4 A-X       A              X               TRUE   
5 B-X       B              X               TRUE   
6 C-X       C              X               FALSE  
7 A-Y       A              Y               FALSE
```

The goal is to construct a `dplyr` pipe that reduces this data frame using the columns `Structure`, `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` so that only the rows remain for which `IsValid == TRUE`. Only those rows should be retained for which the content of `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` can be found in the column `Structure` any where in the data frame:

- rows 1–3 are **invalid** because `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` are `NA`
- rows 4 and 5 are **valid** because both values in `FirstComponent` and `SecondComponent` can be found as values in `Structure`.
- row 6 is **invalid** because the value `C` in `FirstComponent` doesn't occur anywhere as a value of `Structure`.
- row 7 is **invalid** because the value `Y` in `SecondComponent` doesn't occur anywhere else as a value of `Structure`.

(Inspired by the answers to ["How to join a data frame to itself within a dplyr chain?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495473/how-to-join-a-data-frame-to-itself-within-a-dplyr-chain)) I perform self-joins using `Structure` and the information from `FirstComponent` so that rows with values in `FirstComponent` don't have matching values in `Structure` are eliminated, and then feed the result into a second self-join that does the same for `SecondComponent`.

**Working, but impractical code**

The goal is to achieve the filtering within a single `dplyr` pipe. I've found a solution that violates this constraint as it assumes that `dat` exists as a persistent object that can be explicitly provided as the first argument to the `dplyr` methods. In my case, this is not a given. So while the following code does produce the desired result, it's not a solution to the problem:

```r
inner_join(
    x=inner_join(
        x=dat,
        y=select(dat, FirstComponent=Structure)),
    y=select(dat, SecondComponent=Structure))

Joining, by = "FirstComponent"
Joining, by = "SecondComponent"
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Structure FirstComponent SecondComponent IsValid
  <chr>     <chr>          <chr>           <lgl>  
1 A-X       A              X               TRUE   
2 B-X       B              X               TRUE
```

**Failing solution 1**

Simply adding the pipe and replacing all references to `.` produces an error, presumably because the `.` placeholder is out of scope for the nested `inner_join()`:

```r
dat %>%
    inner_join(
        x=inner_join(
            x=.,
            y=select(., FirstComponent=Structure)),
        y=select(., SecondComponent=Structure))
Joining, by = "FirstComponent"
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `x` and `y` don't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**Failing solution 2**

I tried to eliminate the nested `inner_join()` by performing the two self-joins in a strictly consecutive way along the pipe. But this doesn't work either because by the time the second inner-join is reached, the content value of `.` is already reduced to exclude rows 1–3, and hence the eventual result of the second self-join that matches `SecondComponent` to the remaining values of `Structure` yields an empty data frame:

```r
dat %>%
    inner_join(
        x=.,
        y=select(., FirstComponent=Structure)) %>%
    inner_join(
        x=., 
        y=select(., SecondComponent=Structure))

# A tibble: 0 × 4
# … with 4 variables: Structure <chr>, FirstComponent <chr>, SecondComponent <chr>,
#   IsValid <lgl>
```

How do I proceed?

I've considered using a T-pipe as provided by `magrittr`s `%T>%` operator to get around the issue with solution 2, but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a `filter` that looks within the columns of the same dataframe (assuming `Structure` won't have any `NA` values):

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  filter(FirstComponent %in% Structure, SecondComponent %in% Structure)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Structure FirstComponent SecondComponent IsValid
#>   <chr>     <chr>          <chr>           <lgl>  
#> 1 A-X       A              X               TRUE   
#> 2 B-X       B              X               TRUE
```

Comment: You could generalize (if there are more columns to `dat %>% filter(if_all(ends_with("Component"),  ~.x %in% Structure))`